# How to make a Poco::Delegate from a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda, delegates, bind, poco

I have a code like this:

```
void func1(const void *oo, int &a)
{
    ...
}

void test()
{
    auto del1 = Poco::delegate(func1);
}
```

and it works fine, but when i wanna use a lambda function instead of func1 like this code:

```
void test()
{
    auto func2 = [](const void *oo, int &a)
    {
        ...
    };

    auto del1 = Poco::delegate(func2);
}
```

it doesn't work, and give some errors like

```
no matching function for call to 'delegate(test()::<lambda(const void*,
const int&)>&)'
```

How can i make a Poco::Delegate from a lambda, or (more accurate) from result of std::bind?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the lambda is stateless, you could try `Poco::delegate(+func2)`. But that's not a general solution.

Comment: I don't know this library, but from [the documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#10018) it seems that `Poco::delegate` never takes ownership, so you can probably never use a general lambda directly as the function argument, since the callable's lifetime needs to exceed that of the delegate If you create a variable from the lambda first, then you ought to be able to use one of the `delegate` overloads, presumably in a call that involves taking the address of the lambda's `operator()`.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, you right, thank you, it works, very thanks. but now i have some new questions: 1) what is the owner of func1? also +func2? 2) what means "+func2"? where can i read about that? 3) it didn't work for std::function, is there any solution for that too?

Comment: Since your original lambda is stateless, its function call operator is effectively a free function (the unary `+` effects the conversion to a regular function pointer), and there is no object and hence no lifetime issue. A general (capturing) lambda, or a `std::function` for that matter, don't have this peculiar feature, and their call operators are genuine non-static member functions (and hence there is no equivalent "trick").